# Comprobar, antes de eliminar, si una llave foranea esta asociada a otra tabla mysql y java

Tags: java, mysql, crud

Buenas estoy trabajando en un pequeño ejercicio de un CRUD en mysql y java donde puedo agregar, leer, modificar eliminar registros mediante un modelo MVC. En mi base de datos tengo 2 tablas las cuales son deportistas y paises. Entre ellas hay una relacion 1-M donde la foreign key de pais (codPais) esta asociada a la tabla de deportista. Un pais tiene muchos deportistas y un deportista pertenece a un solo pais. Pues la mayor parte del CRUD esta hecha y funciona perfectamente pero lo que quiero es que cuando quiera eliminar un pais, me salte un mensaje de error personalizado (mediante un JOptionPane que yo incorpore) alertando que el pais que se va a eliminar ya esta asociado a un deportista. En caso contrario, que deje eliminarlo. Por el momento solo he podido eliminar el pais eliminando antes el deportista pero eso no seria lo apropiado sino que si el pais que se va a eliminar esta asociado al deportista, que no se elimine y salte el mensaje y si no pues que se elimine. A continuacion coloco el codigo para que vean donde esta el proceso de eliminar.

Este seria de la clase PaisesDAO

```
// ELIMINAR
public void eliminar(Pais p) throws SQLException{
    eliminar(p.getCodPais());
}

private void eliminar(int id) throws SQLException{
    
    if (id <= 0) {
        return;
    }
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM paises WHERE codPais = ?");
    ps.setInt(1, id);
    ps.executeUpdate();
}
```

Y este del controlador

```
// ELIMINAR PAIS
public void eliminarPais() {

    int codPais;
    Pais pais = null;
    PideDatosPais datosPais = new PideDatosPais();
    vistaPaisDeportista mostrar = new vistaPaisDeportista();
    codPais = datosPais.pideCodPais();

    try {
        pais = daop.findByPK(codPais);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (pais == null) {
        System.out.println("EL PAÍS HA ELIMINAR NO ESTÁ EN LA BASE DE DATOS");
    } else {
        
        Object[] opciones = {"SI",
            "NO"};
        int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
                "¿ESTÁ USTED SEGURO DE QUE DESEA ELIMINAR DICHO REGISTRO? (S/N)",
                "¡¡AVISO!!",
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,
                null, //do not use a custom Icon
                opciones,
                opciones[0]);

        if (n == 0) {
            try {
                daop.eliminar(pais);
                mostrar.verPaises(daop.findAll());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Agradezco toda ayuda u opinion gracias

Comment: ¿Por qué no ejecutar el delete y cachar el SQLException?, si tienes las llaves bien en tu base de datos, no te dejará borrar.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar un **try-catch** para capturar la excepción y lanzar el JOptionPane que mencionas. Te muestro como sería la implementación:

```
try {
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM paises WHERE codPais = ?");
    ps.setInt(1, id);
    ps.executeUpdate();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    if (e.getErrorCode() == 1451) { // Verificar si el error es por una restricción FK
        // "El país que se va a eliminar ya está asociado a un deportista.");
    } else {
        // "Error al eliminar el país: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Los comentarios dentro del if, los debes sustituir por tu implementación del JOptionPane.

Para esto, debes tener tu base de datos con las FK establecidas, si no, no funcionará!

Comment: Gracias ya lo pude soluciionar y me va.

Comment: Y si quisiera modificar un deportista y se le agregase un codigo de pais que no existe para que aparezca el mensaje de error de que el pais que se ha introducido no existe, ¿habria que hacer lo mismo?

Comment: Si, pero con el código de error 1452.

Comment: perfecto muchas gracias